# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null at zoom.html:8

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an image zoom where by if you hover over the mouse over the image let it zoom the image on the defined width. Along the line I am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at zoom.html:8
```

in my html file. This is a snippet of the html file I am having the challenge with

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    iw, ih;
```

In the body of the html file I have this snippet

```
<canvas width="310" height="305" id="canvas">Sorry, no canvas available</canvas>
<a id="download" download="download.jpg">Download as image</a>
```

here is a plunk demo I have made

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/0G93qmVeUWby0SRIp5Br
```

Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to access an element in the DOM before it's loaded. Compare these two examples:

```html
<script>
console.log(document.getElementById('canvas'));
</script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
console.log(document.getElementById('canvas'));
</script>
```

As you may have picked up, the solution is to run your script *after* the page is loaded, i.e. at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: Ok cool. Can I make this to reference thesame image used in the body tag  
img.src = "http://www.taaz.com/images/R312W/C3FD4EB9E9BC0CAD2DF3C396288B9291.jpg";

Comment: @parker You've already got an `onload` event listener setup on the `img`. That's what you need to do to work with images.